# passing parameters to insert query

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @SQL1 VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL1='SELECT * FROM tblResponsibleEngineer WHERE ResponsibleEngineer='+CAST(@ResponsibleEngineer AS VARCHAR(500))+''
EXEC(@SQL1)
IF @@ROWCOUNT>0
BEGIN
SET @Result='EXIST'
```

above query fails execution due to the way i pass the parameter `@ResponsibleEngineer` in to the query. error is `"Invalid column name TEST"`. `TEST` is the value i'm passing as the parameter value
`@ResponsibleEngineer` and there is no such column as `TEST` in the table.what the error when passing the parameter to insert query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need speach marks around the Parameter:

```
'SELECT * FROM tblResponsibleEngineer WHERE ResponsibleEngineer='''+CAST(@ResponsibleEngineer AS VARCHAR(500))+''''
```

Otherwise you are generating:

```
SELECT * FROM tblResponsibleEngineer WHERE ResponsibleEngineer=TEST'
```

Therefore its looking for a column `TEST`. By having the parameter in speach marks you are generating:

```
SELECT * FROM tblResponsibleEngineer WHERE ResponsibleEngineer='TEST'
```

This query will then run a `WHERE` clause where the `ResponsibleEngineer` column equals the string value `TEST`

Comment: +1 This would work, the question I had was " Why not use a parameterized query?" when I saw this question though.

Answer (score 0):

you must declare `@ResponsibleEngineer` and set its value. It is basically used as variable.

```
DECLARE @ResponsibleEngineer varchar(10)
SET @ResponsibleEngineer = 'my test'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @SQL1 VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @SQL1='SELECT * FROM tblResponsibleEngineer WHERE ResponsibleEngineer='''+CAST(@ResponsibleEngineer AS VARCHAR(500))+''''
    EXEC(@SQL1)
    IF @@ROWCOUNT>0
    BEGIN
    SET @Result='EXIST'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is translating to

```
 SELECT * FROM tblResponsibleEngineer WHERE ResponsibleEngineer=TEST
```

You need to get the following:

```
 SELECT * FROM tblResponsibleEngineer WHERE ResponsibleEngineer='TEST'
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces around your select. A quick sample

```
DECLARE cnt int
SELECT cnt= count(*) FROM tblResponsibleEngineer WHERE ResponsibleEngineer='CAST(@ResponsibleEngineer AS VARCHAR(500))'
IF cnt>0
BEGIN
  SET @Result='EXIST'
```

Hope this helps.